# How to switch mode from visual/visual line mode to normal mode in Lua?

Tags: neovim

I am writing a comment plugin that supports commenting in visual line mode. I tried using `vim.cmd "stopinsert"` for returning back to normal mode, but it doesn't work. How can I return back to normal mode?

Answer (score 1):

I find out that I can do that with `vim.api.nvim_input("<esc>")`, but I am not sure if there is a better alternative

Comment: Beware that `nvim_input` is non-blocking

Comment: Have you found a better solution yet?